# Git: when to push to branch

Tags: git

- I make a new branch with all my local changes
- I need to split the work I've done into about 10-20 commits.

Do I push once I've made all my commits, or after each commit, or is it personal preference?

Comment: If it's just you working on the project then personal preference otherwise follow what your team has agreed upon IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it depends. If you push your commit it means that it will be at origin and after `git pull` everybody will get this changes. That's why you should be sure that your changes are correct and doesn't brake everything.

If somebody needs your work and waiting, of course you should push correct code as fast as possible.

If you code from work and home, don't forget to push before go home to continue your work at home.

But at all it's a personal question.

Also pay attention that your commits should be logical and atomic. If you have an issue tracking system, link issues and commits by comments. In future it can help if any troubles.

Comment: But if I push my commit on my branch, surely only those who have my branch will get the changes? (Not saying everything shouldn't be correct, because obviously the branch will be merged eventually, just asking whether everybody would get the things I pushed to my branch or not.)

Comment: If this branch pushed to origin - yes, everybody will get. If local branch - no.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If the commits are huge. The best thing to do is to push them instantly. That is the safest thing to do. If something happens to your pc, it will be backed-up.

Although pushing after every tiny commit you did might be a bit over the top. Think about it as saving a word file. You don't save after every sentence, but after a few paragraphs it might be wise to save the document!

But it's mostly personal preference!

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I've already done all the work (but failed to commit as I went along), it'll be a series of quick commits, so I guess I can just push at the end.

Comment: @aurumpotestasest Yes, if you are just “repackaging” your work into commits, it’s good enough if you just push once at the end. In general, I would prefer this anyway for a series of related commits as you won’t run into conflicts multiple times when someone else pushed in between, and to keep your commits together.

Answer (score 1):

Push as often as possible, because that also backups your work. But ensure that the commits do not break the continuous integration (do not contain compile-errors or failed unit tests, etc.).

In my opinion using small commits, as you do, is good practice:
http://www.crealytics.de/blog/2010/07/09/5-reasons-keeping-git-commits-small-admin/

but some open-source projects prefer one big feature patch, such that their master revision history is not flooded.

EDIT: (Just saw viakondratiuk answer)

I also work with two machines and therefore use a personal branch to be able to push my work-in-progress stuff. When I merge back into the feature branch I combine the (WIP) commits to one commit, such that every commit works.

Answer (score 1):

If you collaborate with others, and you are not using your own personal repository, push only when it is mostly bug free (and builds).  If you do not collaborate, push as often as possible as it is a good way to backup your work.

This is where forked repositories are nice.  Push often and rewrite history when bugs are found, then submit a pull request.